# Extending or overriding a formatter in UI5

Tags: sapui5

I am extending a SAP stock Fiori App (Approve Purchase Orders). It has its formatters in /util/Conversions.js. I specifically want to extend the formatter "accountingFormatter". My goal would be to prefix the normal outcome, say "Cost Center 123" with a custom field to result in "K - Cost Center 123".

I followed [this guide](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/07/27/overriding-source-files-in-the-util-folder-when-extendingcustomising-fiori-apps/) on the SAP community. My own /util/Conversions.js file looks like this

```
// extending or trying to do so a built in formatter for accounting information

// declaring my extended formatter in the extended util/Conversions.js
// the MM_PO_APVExtension here is the name of the extended app, taken e.g. from Component.js
jQuery.sap.declare("ui.s2p.mm.purchorder.approve.MM_PO_APVExtension.util.Conversions");

// referencing the standard formatter in the non extended util/Conversions.js
jQuery.sap.require("ui.s2p.mm.purchorder.approve.util.Conversions");

// now actually redefining / overriding the standard formatter
ui.s2p.mm.purchorder.approve.util.Conversions.accountingFormatter = function(oHeaderInfo) {
    // exit when not yet ready
    if (!oHeaderInfo) {return;};
    
    // Debug
    return 'This is from the new custom formatter, but how to call the original one?';
}
```

My problem is:

How could I call the original formatter now that I "buldozered over" using the "jQuery.sap.declare" and "jQuery.sap.require"?
Was / is this approach even the way one would do it? If not, how could I extend the formatter without basically copying the code from the standard formatter?

I tried with calling "ui.s2p.mm.purchorder.approve.util.Conversions.accountingFormatter(oHeaderInfo);" but that just calls my above own implementation (of course).

Many thanks and cheers
Jens